# Where did I gain the power to perform Chaotic Rituals?

Tags: mods, torchlight-2

Doing a quick search of the spell name "evoke/invoke chaotic ritual!" yielded me nothing. Because of that, I'm assuming it came from the Synergies mod. Is there any more information on this somewhere, or does anyone know more about it?

When I use it, it summons bosses from any point in the game, and also creates very high level gear and legendaries. (Like numerous 99/100 level req stuff). I found it somewhere in the 2nd act before beating the artificer.